# Redis hash key deleted automatically from server

Tags: redis

I am using redis for few months but now redis hash key deleted automatically form server. I am using master slave architecture also my site meet lacks of users per hour. Can any one help me how to solve this issue..... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Start by checking the content of Redis configuration file (maxmemory and maxmemory-policy) parameters to see if some automatic eviction is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the right max-memorypolicy (you probably dont want allkeys-lru because redis will expire least accessed keys regardless of them having an expiration or not).

You should also make sure that redis has enough memory to store the keys you dont want to expire or get evicted by redis. (redis maxmemory config compared to system memory)

If you use no-eviction policy make sure redis will never run out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.Currently we are have 6GB maxmemory in Rredis.conf and maxmemory-policy is volatile-lru(Default Value).But still we are facing the issue when there is concurrent redis connection.Kindly help us to solve the issue.

Comment: @Lingesh that sounds like a different problem, can you open an new question for it ?